# ¿Como llama la informacion de un metodo a otro?

Tags: java, poo

necesito calcular la atracion gravitacional de dos cuerpos celestes.
por lo cual quisiera que me ayudaran a como llamo a la info de los metodos infoinfoEarth con todos sus atributos y al igual  que infoMarth(), y llevarlos a gravitationalAttraction() para poder hacer la formula de fg= (g*(m1*m2)) acontinuacion dejo los metodos, todos estos metodos los sobre escribo del clase bodySystem, donde estan todos sus contructores y atributos, en resumen necesitaria la info de tierra y la info de marte para calcular su fuerza gravitacional sin volver a asignarles valores.

```
    //Variable de la gravedad universal
    private final float Gravity = 6.67f;
//Metodo  InfoErth
    @Override
        public void infoEarth() {
            
            bodySystem systemEarth = new bodySystem();
            systemEarth.setId(1);
            systemEarth.setName("Earth");
            systemEarth.setMass(5.97f);
            systemEarth.setDensity(5.52f);
            systemEarth.setDiameter(14.714f);
            systemEarth.setDistanceSun(149.6f);
            System.out.println(systemEarth);  
            
  //MetodoInfoMarth  
     @Override
        public void infoMarth() {
            bodySystem systemMarth = new bodySystem();
            systemMarth.setId(2);
            systemMarth.setName("Marth");
            systemMarth.setMass(6.39f);
            systemMarth.setDensity(3.93f);
            systemMarth.setDiameter(6.779f);
            systemMarth.setDistanceSun(227.9f);
            System.out.println(systemMarth);
        }
     @Override
        public void gravitationalAttraction() {
           
        }
```

cuando los intento llamar se me sobre escribe los metodos setmass y me da cero.

Comment: Hola Jaime, para poder contestar, necesitamos ver la clase **bodySystem**, debería tener un **getter** al que invocas con **getMass()** (o algo parecido) para obtener la masa y otra **getDistanceSun()**, nota: ojo que **fg= (g*(m1*m2))** no es correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es que ambos métodos devuelvan el objeto bodySystem.

Luego en el gravitationalAttraction() podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
bodySystem earth = infoEarth();
bodySystem marth = infoMarth();
```

Luego haces la ecucación con los datos que necesitas de cada cuerpo.

Una cosa por si te interesa: como convención en Java, las clases comienzan en mayúscula. Sería BodySystem.
Te dejo un artículo donde mencionan algunas de las convenciones:
https://programacion.net/articulo/convenciones_de_codificacion_en_java_105/9

Comment: Incluso podrías tener un sólo método que reciba los valores:

`public void info(int id, String name, float mass, etc etc)`